# jquery looping include php

Tags: jquery

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(){

var pilaMan = 2;

for (i=0; i < pilaMan; i++)
    {

    $('#dialog_link').dialog({
                modal: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 800,
                height: 300,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() { 
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    }, 
                    "Cancel": function() { 
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    } 
                }
            });

    $('#dialog' + i).click(function(){
                $('#dialog_link' ).dialog('open');
                var lineCode = $('#lineCode').currentElem.prev().val();

                alert(lineCode);

                return false;

            });


    }
```

});

**My Problem with my jquery Code i cant get the exact value of** $amew.. and also when i alert the  *lineCode* it will return undefined :(

**php code:**

```
$amew = "loso nimo";
$count = 0;
$array = explode(" ", $amew) 

foreach ($array as $value) {

    echo '<td width="68" class="rep" id="dialog'.$count.'">';
    echo '<input type="text" id="lineCode" value="'.$value.'">';

    echo '</td';


}
```

**my problem with my php code is so redundant my jquery codes** 
i solving this for 10 hours and still i cant get it need help guys:(

Comment: Well first of all you can only use the id `lineCode` once in the entire document. `id` attributes must be unique. Try changing it co the class name and adjusting your js accordingly. I fthat doesnt work update your questions with an new information.

Comment: yeah.. i try it before lineCode'.$count.' to make it unique but it will return undifined..  whats wrong with my code? :(

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what's being asked -- a few things I noticed is that if you have an ID in a loop (like "lineCode"), there is no way for jQuery to know which one to grab. Also, it looks like you have a single quote in your id tag:

id="lineCode'"

instead of

id="lineCode"

---

Revised:

PHP Code:

```
$amew = "loso nimo";
$count = 0;
$array = explode(" ", $amew) 

foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo '<td width="68" class="rep" id="dialog'.$count.'">';
    echo '<input type="text" id="lineCode' . $count . '" value="'.$value.'">';

    echo '</td>';

    $count++;
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var pilaMan = 2;

    $('#dialog_link').dialog({
        modal: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 800,
        height: 300,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            }, 
            "Cancel": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            } 
        }
    });

    for( i = 0; i < pilaMan; i++) {
        $('#dialog' + i).click( function(){
            $('#dialog_link' ).dialog('open');
            alert( $('#lineCode' + i).val() );

            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry.. ^^ i have two loops (loso and nimo) my problem is how can i get each value when i click dialog0 it will return loso and when i click dialog1 it will return nimo.. tnx

Comment: just to simplify things for some, you can use `echo "text".$count++."moretext";`